# Summation of a sequence which is neither arithmetic nor geometric

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \dfrac{1}{1-x^{1/2}} + \dfrac{1}{1-x} + \dfrac{1}{1+x^{1/2}} + \cdots n\ \text{terms} $$

I couldn't figure out its sum as it isn't a Geometric Series nor an Arithmetic Series. I guess it can be converted into G.S or A.S but I don't know how! I tried but I am stuck!

Comment: What do you know about convergence of a series ??

Comment: What's the rule for the sign of $x^k$ in the denominator? Is there a typo in the third term or is there a more complicated rule?

Comment: The three terms you have typed don't tell us what the series is.

Comment: Well! That was all. The question in the book was to sum the series. Nothing about its convergence is given and yes only first 3 terms have been given.

Comment: What's the general term of the sequence?

Comment: Mostafa Ayaz! If the general term had been given I would have solved it by now!